# Oracle PM Schema download

Tags: oracle, plsql

Trying to learn PL/SQL with multimedia data. Can anyone please point out that from where I can download Oracle PM sample schema? Oracle is pointing to Oracle Home directory in my system but there is only HR schema there and can't find any link online where I can download it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK.  Are you stating that when you look in the database server's Oracle Home, you don't have a file `$ORACLE_HOME/demo/schema/product_media\pm_main.sql`?

What version of Oracle are you using?  With 10.2, I believe the sample schemas were on the companion CD.  If you're using 11.2, you should just be able to open up the Oracle Universal Installer (OUI) and add the sample schemas to your Oracle Home if they're not already installed.

Comment: Ty will look into, just noticed have to install OE schema before I can install PM schema as it has dependencies.